# Procedural Island Terrain Generation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, terrain, perlin-noise, procedural-generation

*Edit: Rewrote my question after trying a few things and made it more specific.*

Hi, so I'm creating a **mobile RTS game with procedurally generated maps**. I've worked out how to create a terrain with a basic perlin noise on it, and tried to integrate https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/54276/a-simple-method-to-create-island-map-mask method to creating an island procedurally. This is the result so far:

[image]

The image below from http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/ shows the kind of terrain I'm after. The tutorial there is great but would be too intensive, thus the post.

I want the Random Shaped island with Perlin noise generated land mass, surrounded by water.

[image: This is the kind of shaping I want]

*edit: Basic Perlin terrain gen working now =)*

Here is my code. A script attached to a null with a button to activate Begin():

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Gen_Perlin : MonoBehaviour {

public float Tiling = 0.5f;
private bool active = false;
public int mapHeight = 10;

public void Begin()
{
    if (active == false) {
        TerrainData terrainData = new TerrainData ();
        const int size = 513;
        terrainData.heightmapResolution = size;
        terrainData.size = new Vector3 (2000, mapHeight, 2000);

        terrainData.heightmapResolution = 513;
        terrainData.baseMapResolution = 1024;
        terrainData.SetDetailResolution (1024, 1024);

        Terrain.CreateTerrainGameObject (terrainData);
        GameObject obj = GameObject.Find ("Terrain");
        obj.transform.parent = this.transform;

        if (obj.GetComponent<Terrain> ()) {
            GenerateHeights (obj.GetComponent<Terrain> (), Tiling);
        }
    } else {
        GameObject obj = GameObject.Find ("Terrain");
        if (obj.GetComponent<Terrain> ()) {
            GenerateHeights (obj.GetComponent<Terrain> (), Tiling);
        }
    }
}

public void GenerateHeights(Terrain terrain, float tileSize)
{
    Debug.Log ("Start_Height_Gen");
    float[,] heights = new float[terrain.terrainData.heightmapWidth, terrain.terrainData.heightmapHeight];

    for (int i = 0; i < terrain.terrainData.heightmapWidth; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < terrain.terrainData.heightmapHeight; k++)
        {
            heights[i, k] = 0.25f + Mathf.PerlinNoise(((float)i / (float)terrain.terrainData.heightmapWidth) * tileSize, ((float)k / (float)terrain.terrainData.heightmapHeight) * tileSize);
            heights[i, k] *= makeMask( terrain.terrainData.heightmapWidth, terrain.terrainData.heightmapHeight, i, k, heights[i, k] );
        }
    }
    terrain.terrainData.SetHeights(0, 0, heights);
}

public static float makeMask( int width, int height, int posX, int posY, float oldValue ) {
    int minVal = ( ( ( height + width ) / 2 ) / 100 * 2 );
    int maxVal = ( ( ( height + width ) / 2 ) / 100 * 10 );
    if( getDistanceToEdge( posX, posY, width, height ) <= minVal ) {
        return 0;
    } else if( getDistanceToEdge( posX, posY, width, height ) >= maxVal ) {
        return oldValue;
    } else {
        float factor = getFactor( getDistanceToEdge( posX, posY, width, height ), minVal, maxVal );
        return oldValue * factor;
    }
}

private static float getFactor( int val, int min, int max ) {
    int full = max - min;
    int part = val - min;
    float factor = (float)part / (float)full;
    return factor;
}

public static int getDistanceToEdge( int x, int y, int width, int height ) {
    int[] distances = new int[]{ y, x, ( width - x ), ( height - y ) };
    int min = distances[ 0 ];
    foreach( var val in distances ) {
        if( val < min ) {
            min = val;
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

}

Comment: see [simple island map generator in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36647622/2521214)

Comment: Nice getting it working! Next step I would suggest replacing Mathf.PerlinNoise with an imported lib with a good 2D simplex implementation. Perlin noise has the problem of being very grid-aligned. You could import `Unity.Mathematics.noise.snoise(float2)` or use [this](https://github.com/KdotJPG/OpenSimplex2/blob/master/java/OpenSimplex2F.java). The latter would probably be faster since you aren't using Burst jobs, which optimize Unity.Mathematics noise.

Comment: Oh wow I did not see how old this post was! I think it showed up in my newest-sorted search results because there is a recent reply. Hope my comment is useful to someone regardless!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah. The article in question is using a waaay complex method.

The best way of doing this is to take a function that represents the shape of your basic island, with height values between 0 and 1. For the type of island in the picture, you'd basically want something which smoothly rises from the edges, and smoothly dips back to zero where you want lakes.

Now you either add that surface to your basic fractal surface (if you want to preserve spikiness at low elevations) or you multiply it (if you want lower elevations to be smooth). Then you define a height, below which is water.

Here is my very quick go at doing this, rendered with Terragen:

[image: Ring Island - Quick and Dirty attempt]

I used a function that rises in a ring from the edge of the map to halfway to the middle, then drops again, to match a similar shape to the one from the article. In practice, you might only use this to get the shape of the island, and then carve the bit of terrain that matches the contour, and bury everything else.

I used my own fractal landscape generator as described here: https://fractal-landscapes.co.uk for the basic fractal.

Here is the C# code that modifies the landscape:

```
public void MakeRingIsland()
{
    this.Normalize(32768);
    var ld2 = (double) linearDimension / 2;
    var ld4 = 4 / (double) linearDimension;
    for (var y = 0u; y < linearDimension; y++)
    {
        var yMul = y * linearDimension;
        for (var x = 0u; x < linearDimension; x++)
        {
            var yCoord = (y - ld2) * ld4;
            var xCoord = (x - ld2) * ld4;
            var dist = Math.Sqrt(xCoord * xCoord + yCoord * yCoord);
            var htMul = dist > 2 ? 0 : 
                (dist < 1 ? 
                    dist + dist - dist * dist : 
                    1 - (dist - 1) * (dist - 1));
            var height = samples[x + yMul];
            samples[x + yMul] = (int) (height + htMul * 32768);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works well! Note that I would probably avoid the Math.sqrt in the distance function, and just use squared distance. Divide it by the width or the height to rescale it to the same rough range. The sqrt could cause a sharp point in the middle, and also introduces extra computational cost you might not need.

Comment: The sqrt is needed for a smooth piecewise rise and fall. Basically it's putting two quadratics back-to-back, to get a donut shape. Of course, you could avoid it with a different basis function, and you could make a lookup table to avoid doing it for more than at most 1/8 of the points. Also, the code is as simple as possible for the purposes of clarity - I wouldn't really write it this way, or use exactly this method. There are issues with it.

Comment: For a real method that does the same thing, you can use the isoline of an altitude contour to define the shape of the island (basically use this method for the shoreline), but then define a multiplication function which is zero or negative for the sea, and scaled according to the distance inland from the shore. That would avoid the barrel-roll shape you get from the donut.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify that I am not the OP. I only found this because it showed up in a search result for terrain related topics, sorted by newest. And I do see the point of the sqrt now! There is a sharp point, but it will be below the water level. It could still matter in an application which shows the underwater terrain, but not here as long as the noise range can't pull the point to the surface. [Wolfram Visualization](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+Piecewise%5B%7B%7Bd%2Bd-d*d%2C+d+%3C+1%7D%2C+%7B1+-+%28d-1%29*%28d-1%29%2C+d+%3E%3D+1%7D%7D%5D+where+d+%3D+sqrt%28x*x%2By*y%29)

Answer (score 1):

the image you are showing comes from [article](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/) describing how to generate it

Comment: I know, but that method is quite complex. I was thinking more along the lines of perhaps using a mask for the basic shape.

Comment: It's also too intensive for a mobile device