# how to create a branching vein/river like structure on a square grid

Tags: algorithm, lua, grid, procedural-generation

I am trying to procedurally generate some rivers.

I have a flat (no concept of elevation) square grid as base and want to draw a branching structure on it like shown in the image.

Can you share the steps that one may use to get that done?

I am not looking for the fastest implementation as there is no real time generation, but the simpler implementation will be prefered. Lua is my language but anything will do.

Few more things:

1. The shape should be generated algorithmic ally.
2. The shape should be
   controllable using a seed value.

[image]

Comment: Sidenote: Branching rivers like this _almost never_ happen in real life. It's exactly the other way around, where multiple tributaries combine into a single river; a reverse tree. The branching you propose might be best used for specific types of estuaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think generating rivers is a backward approach as you would need to tweak a lot of things according to their shape later on which will be hard. I would instead create random terrain height map and extract features from it (as in the real world) which is much easier and closer to reality. In the final map you ignore the height and use flat one (if you really want a flat map). Here are few things you can extract from height map:

1. **Rivers and lakes**

   by seeding random high altitude point and following it downhill to sea level or edge of map.
2. **vegetation or ground**

   from slope and altitude you can determine if ground is sand,dirt,rock. If there are trees, bushes, grass or whatever.

Here look at this **QA**: [random island generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36647622/2521214)

and some river overview:

[image: island rivers]

The way you tweak the terrain generation will affect also the river shapes (no need to generate just islands).

The Seeds are working also for this approach.

**[Edit1] promised C++ code**

This basically generate random height map and then seed and downhill follow the rivers (lakes are generated automatically if the terrain block downhill watter flow). The terrain type is also determined from slope and altitude.

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
picture pic;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void map_random(int _xs,int _ys)
    {
    // config
    int   h0=-1000,h1=3000;     // [m] terrain elevation range
    int   h_water= 0;           // [m] sea level
    int   h_sand=15;            // [m] sand level
    int   h_evergreen=1500;     // [m] evergreen level
    int   h_snow=2000;          // [m] snow level
    int   h_rock=1800;          // [m] mountine rock level
    float a_rock=60.0;          // [deg] mountine rock slope
    float d_pixel=35.0;         // [m] pixel size
    int   d_river_w=5;          // [pixel] river max width
    int   d_river_l=150;        // [pixel] river base length per width increase
    bool _island=true;

    // types
    enum _cover_enum
        {
        _cover_none=0,
        _cover_water,   // sea
        _cover_snow,
        _covers,
        _cover_shift=0,
        _cover_mask=15,
        };
    DWORD _cover[_covers]=
        {
        //  RRGGBB
        0x00000000,     // none
        0x00003080,     // watter (sea)
        0x00EEEEEE,     // snow
        };
    enum _terrain_enum
        {
        _terrain_dirt=0,
        _terrain_sand,
        _terrain_rock,
        _terrain_water, // streams,rivers,lakes
        _terrain_temp,  // temp
        _terrains,
        _terrain_shift=4,
        _terrain_mask=15,
        };
    DWORD _terrain[_terrains]=
        {
        //  RRGGBB
        0x00301510,     // dirt
        0x00EEC49A,     // sand
        0x006F6F6F,     // rock
        0x00006080,     // water (streams,rivers,lakes)
        0x00006080,     // temp
        };
    enum _flora_enum
        {
        _flora_none=0,
        _flora_grass,
        _flora_hardwood,
        _flora_evergreen,
        _flora_deadwood,
        _floras,
        _flora_shift=8,
        _flora_mask=15,
        };
    DWORD _flora[_floras]=
        {
        //  RRGGBB
        0x00000000,     // none
        0x007F7F3F,     // grass
        0x001FFF1F,     // hardwood
        0x00007F00,     // evergreen
        0x007F3F1F,     // deadwood
        };

    // variables
    float a,b,da; int c,t,f;
    int x,y,z,xx,yy,mxs,mys,dx,dy,dx2,dy2,r,r2,ix,l;
    int xh1,yh1;    // topest hill position
    int **ter=NULL,**typ=NULL;
    Randomize();
    // align resolution to power of 2
    for (mxs=1;mxs+1<_xs;mxs<<=1); if (mxs<3) mxs=3;
    for (mys=1;mys+1<_ys;mys<<=1); if (mys<3) mys=3;
    ter=new int*[mys+1]; for (y=0;y<=mys;y++) ter[y]=new int[mxs+1];
    typ=new int*[mys+1]; for (y=0;y<=mys;y++) typ[y]=new int[mxs+1];

    // [Terrain]
    for (;;)
        {
        // diamond & square random height map -> ter[][]
        dx=mxs; dx2=dx>>1; r=(mxs+mys)<<1;          // init step,half step and randomness
        dy=mys; dy2=dy>>1; r2=r>>1;
        // set corners values
        if (_island)
            {
            t=-r2;
            ter[  0][  0]=t;
            ter[  0][mxs]=t;
            ter[mys][  0]=t;
            ter[mys][mxs]=t;
            ter[dy2][dx2]=r+r;  // top of central hill
            }
        else{
            ter[  0][  0]=Random(r);
            ter[  0][mxs]=Random(r);
            ter[mys][  0]=Random(r);
            ter[mys][mxs]=Random(r);
            }
        for (;dx2|dy2;dx=dx2,dx2>>=1,dy=dy2,dy2>>=1)    // subdivide step until full image is filled
            {
            if (!dx) dx=1;
            if (!dy) dy=1;
            // diamond (skip first one for islands)
            if ((!_island)||(dx!=mxs))
             for (y=dy2,yy=mys-dy2;y<=yy;y+=dy)
              for (x=dx2,xx=mxs-dx2;x<=xx;x+=dx)
               ter[y][x]=((ter[y-dy2][x-dx2]+ter[y-dy2][x+dx2]+ter[y+dy2][x-dx2]+ter[y+dy2][x+dx2])>>2)+Random(r)-r2;
            // square
            for (y=dy2,yy=mys-dy2;y<=yy;y+=dy)
             for (x=dx ,xx=mxs-dx ;x<=xx;x+=dx)
              ter[y][x]=((ter[y][x-dx2]+ter[y][x+dx2]+ter[y-dy2][x]+ter[y+dy2][x])>>2)+Random(r)-r2;
            for (y=dy ,yy=mys-dy ;y<=yy;y+=dy)
             for (x=dx2,xx=mxs-dx2;x<=xx;x+=dx)
              ter[y][x]=((ter[y][x-dx2]+ter[y][x+dx2]+ter[y-dy2][x]+ter[y+dy2][x])>>2)+Random(r)-r2;
            for (x=dx2,xx=mxs-dx2;x<=xx;x+=dx)
                {
                y=  0; ter[y][x]=((ter[y][x-dx2]+ter[y][x+dx2]+ter[y+dy2][x])/3)+Random(r)-r2;
                y=mys; ter[y][x]=((ter[y][x-dx2]+ter[y][x+dx2]+ter[y-dy2][x])/3)+Random(r)-r2;
                }
            for (y=dy2,yy=mys-dy2;y<=yy;y+=dy)
                {
                x=  0; ter[y][x]=((ter[y][x+dx2]+ter[y-dy2][x]+ter[y+dy2][x])/3)+Random(r)-r2;
                x=mxs; ter[y][x]=((ter[y][x-dx2]+ter[y-dy2][x]+ter[y+dy2][x])/3)+Random(r)-r2;
                }
            if (_island)
                {
                // recompute middle position after first pass so there can be more central hills
                if (dx==mxs) ter[dy2][dx2]=Random(r2);
                // adjust border to underwatter
                for (y=0;y<=mys;y+=dy2) { ter[y][0]=t; ter[y][mxs]=t; }
                for (x=0;x<=mxs;x+=dx2) { ter[0][x]=t; ter[mys][x]=t; }
                }
            // adjust randomness
            r>>=1; if (r<2) r=2; r2=r>>1;
            }
        // rescale to <h0,h1>
        xx=ter[0][0]; yy=xx;
        for (y=0;y<=mys;y++)
         for (x=0;x<=mxs;x++)
            {
            z=ter[y][x];
            if (xx>z)  xx=z;
            if (yy<z){ yy=z; xh1=x; yh1=y; }
            }
        for (y=0;y<=mys;y++)
         for (x=0;x<=mxs;x++)
          ter[y][x]=h0+(((ter[y][x]-xx)*(h1-h0))/(yy-xx));
        // test for correctness
        if (_island)
            {
            l=0;
            for (x=0;x<=mxs;x++) { if (ter[0][x]>h_water) l++; if (ter[mys][x]>h_water) l++; }
            for (y=0;y<=mys;y++) { if (ter[y][0]>h_water) l++; if (ter[y][mxs]>h_water) l++; }
            if (l>1+((mxs+mys)>>3)) continue;
            }
        break;
        }

    // [Surface]
    for (y=0;y<mys;y++)
     for (x=0;x<mxs;x++)
        {
        z=ter[y][x];
        // max slope [deg]
        a=atan2(ter[y][x+1]-z,d_pixel);
        b=atan2(ter[y+1][x]-z,d_pixel);
        if (a<b) a=b; a*=180.0/M_PI;

        c=_cover_none;
        if (z<=h_water) c=_cover_water;
        if (z>=h_snow ) c=_cover_snow;

        t=_terrain_dirt;
        if (z<=h_sand)  t=_terrain_sand;
        if (z>=h_rock)  t=_terrain_rock;
        if (a>=a_rock)  t=_terrain_rock;

        f=_flora_none;
        if (t==_terrain_dirt)
            {
            r=Random(100);
            if (r>10) f=_flora_grass;
            if (r>50)
                {
                if (z>h_evergreen) f=_flora_evergreen;
                else{
                    r=Random(h_evergreen);
                    if (r<=z) f=_flora_evergreen;
                    else      f=_flora_hardwood;
                    }
                }
            if (r<5) f=_flora_deadwood;
            }
        typ[y][x]=(c<<_cover_shift)|(t<<_terrain_shift)|(f<<_flora_shift);
        }

    // [Rivers]
    for (ix=10+Random(5),a=0.0,da=2.0*M_PI/float(ix);ix;ix--)
        {
        // random start around topest hill
        a+=da*(0.75+(0.50*Random()));
        for (l=0;l<10;l++)
            {
            b=Random(mxs>>3);
            x=xh1; x+=float(b*cos(a));
            y=yh1; y+=float(b*sin(a));
            if ((x<1)||(x>=mxs)) continue;
            if ((y<1)||(y>=mys)) continue;
            if (typ[y][x]&0x00F==_cover_water) continue;
            l=-1;
            break;
            } if (l>=0) continue; // safety check
        for (l=0,r2=0;;)
            {
            // stop on map edge
            if ((x<=0)||(x>=mxs-1)||(y<=0)||(y>=mys-1)) break;
            // decode generated surface
            r=typ[y][x];
            c=(r>>  _cover_shift)&  _cover_mask;
            t=(r>>_terrain_shift)&_terrain_mask;
            f=(r>>  _flora_shift)&  _flora_mask;
            // stop if reached sea
            if (c==_cover_water) break;
            // insert river dot radius = r2
            dx=x-r2; if (dx<0) dx=0; dx2=x+r2; if (dx2>=mxs) dx2=mxs-1;
            dy=y-r2; if (dy<0) dy=0; dy2=y+r2; if (dy2>=mys) dy2=mys-1;
            for (yy=dy;yy<=dy2;yy++)
             for (xx=dx;xx<=dx2;xx++)
              if (((xx-x)*(xx-x))+((yy-y)*(yy-y))<=r2*r2)
               if (((typ[yy][xx]>>_terrain_shift)&_terrain_mask)!=_terrain_water)
                typ[yy][xx]=(typ[yy][xx]&0x00F)|(_terrain_temp<<_terrain_shift);
            // step to smalest elevation neighbor
            dx=x;   dy=y; z=h1; typ[y][x]=(typ[y][x]&0x00F)|(_terrain_water<<_terrain_shift); xx=x; yy=y;
            xx--; r=ter[yy][xx]; if ((z>=r)&&(((typ[yy][xx]>>_terrain_shift)&_terrain_mask)!=_terrain_water)) { z=r; dx=xx; dy=yy; }
            yy--; r=ter[yy][xx]; if ((z>=r)&&(((typ[yy][xx]>>_terrain_shift)&_terrain_mask)!=_terrain_water)) { z=r; dx=xx; dy=yy; }
            xx++; r=ter[yy][xx]; if ((z>=r)&&(((typ[yy][xx]>>_terrain_shift)&_terrain_mask)!=_terrain_water)) { z=r; dx=xx; dy=yy; }
            xx++; r=ter[yy][xx]; if ((z>=r)&&(((typ[yy][xx]>>_terrain_shift)&_terrain_mask)!=_terrain_water)) { z=r; dx=xx; dy=yy; }
            yy++; r=ter[yy][xx]; if ((z>=r)&&(((typ[yy][xx]>>_terrain_shift)&_terrain_mask)!=_terrain_water)) { z=r; dx=xx; dy=yy; }
            yy++; r=ter[yy][xx]; if ((z>=r)&&(((typ[yy][xx]>>_terrain_shift)&_terrain_mask)!=_terrain_water)) { z=r; dx=xx; dy=yy; }
            xx--; r=ter[yy][xx]; if ((z>=r)&&(((typ[yy][xx]>>_terrain_shift)&_terrain_mask)!=_terrain_water)) { z=r; dx=xx; dy=yy; }
            xx--; r=ter[yy][xx]; if ((z>=r)&&(((typ[yy][xx]>>_terrain_shift)&_terrain_mask)!=_terrain_water)) { z=r; dx=xx; dy=yy; }
            if ((dx==x)&&(dy==y))
                {
                // handle invalid path or need for a lake!!!
                if (dx>mxs>>1) dx++; else dx--;
                if (dy>mys>>1) dy++; else dy--;
                }
            x=dx; y=dy;
            // increase river volume with length
            l++; if (l>d_river_l*(r2+1)) { l=0; if (r2<d_river_w) r2++; }
            }
        // make merging of rivers possible
        for (y=0;y<=mys;y++)
         for (x=0;x<=mxs;x++)
          if (((typ[y][x]>>_terrain_shift)&_terrain_mask)==_terrain_water)
           typ[y][x]=(typ[y][x]&0x00F)|(_terrain_temp<<_terrain_shift);
        }
    for (y=0;y<=mys;y++)
     for (x=0;x<=mxs;x++)
      if (((typ[y][x]>>_terrain_shift)&_terrain_mask)==_terrain_temp)
       typ[y][x]=(typ[y][x]&0x00F)|(_terrain_water<<_terrain_shift);


    // [copy data] rewrite this part to suite your needs
    for (y=1;y<_ys;y++)
     for (x=1;x<_xs;x++)
        {
        float nx,ny,nz,x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1;
        // (nx,ny,nz) = surface normal
        nx=0.0;      ny=0.0; nz=ter[y][x];
        x0=-d_pixel; y0=0.0; z0=ter[y][x-1];
        x1=0.0; y1=-d_pixel; z1=ter[y-1][x];
        x0-=nx; x1-=nx;
        y0-=ny; y1-=ny;
        z0-=nz; z1-=nz;
        nx=(y0*z1)-(z0*y1);
        ny=(z0*x1)-(x0*z1);
        nz=(x0*y1)-(y0*x1);
        x0=1.0/sqrt((nx*nx)+(ny*ny)+(nz*nz));
        nx*=x0;
        ny*=x0;
        nz*=x0;
        // z = ambient light + normal shading
        nz=(+0.7*nx)+(-0.7*ny)+(+0.7*nz);
        if (nz<0.0) nz=0.0;
        nz=255.0*(0.2+(0.8*nz)); z=nz;
        // r = base color
        r=typ[y][x];
        c=(r>>  _cover_shift)&  _cover_mask;
        t=(r>>_terrain_shift)&_terrain_mask;
        f=(r>>  _flora_shift)&  _flora_mask;
               r=_terrain[t];
        if (c) r=  _cover[c];
        if (f){ if (c) r|=_flora[f]; else r=_flora[f]; };
        // sea color is depending on depth not surface normal
        if (c==_cover_water) z=256-((ter[y][x]<<7)/h0);
        // apply lighting z to color r
        yy=int(r>>16)&255; yy=(yy*z)>>8; if (yy>255) yy=255; r=(r&0x0000FFFF)|(yy<<16);
        yy=int(r>> 8)&255; yy=(yy*z)>>8; if (yy>255) yy=255; r=(r&0x00FF00FF)|(yy<< 8);
        yy=int(r    )&255; yy=(yy*z)>>8; if (yy>255) yy=255; r=(r&0x00FFFF00)|(yy    );
        // set pixel to target image
        pic.p[y][x].dd=r;
        }

    // free ter[][],typ[][]
    for (y=0;y<=mys;y++) delete[] ter[y]; delete[] ter; ter=NULL;
    for (y=0;y<=mys;y++) delete[] typ[y]; delete[] typ; typ=NULL;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The code is based on the code from the linked Answer of mine but with added features (rivers included). I use my own picture class for images so some members are:

- `xs,ys` size of image in pixels
- `p[y][x].dd` is pixel at `(x,y)` position as 32 bit integer type
- `clear(color)` - clears entire image
- `resize(xs,ys)` - resizes image to new resolution
- `bmp` - VCL encapsulated GDI Bitmap with Canvas access

You can tweak the `adjust randomness` in **Diamond&Square** to change the terrain smoothness. Also the height limits and tresholds can be tampered with.

To achieve more brunching like rivers seed more start points in clusters so they should merge in time into single or more rivers.

Comment: I do have an island with elevation and moisture but the gradients are a bit too smooth for my taste. Often the rivers come as a straight line. So i want to generate the river first and then go from there.

I would reduce the elevation and increase moisture of all tiles near a river and call them valleys. this will also make the island much more interesting.

Comment: @RishavSharan may be adding more noise to the height would solve this better but I know what you mean on My generated islands the rivers are not that branchy either but never a straight line. So may be is something wrong with your height map generation What approach you use? I am on Diamond&Square which have great scalability control options.

Comment: I went with Amit's tutorial with some changes on my side.
Here's my island:
https://imgur.com/a/rqFOL

I am going for the exact same approach you have outlines. Use elevation to define the river tiles. Also use length to define the broadening of the river.

But in practice, it just doesnt looks good in my map. :(
so i wanted to start with good looking rivers rather than the other (ideal) way around.

Here's my code:
https://github.com/rishavs/KingdomFail_love2d/

Comment: As I cant edit my above comment anymore,    

more importantly, my current approach gives me multiple hills and mountains instead of a single mountain in the middle of the island.

Comment: @RishavSharan That image of yours looks like the downhill path of yours does not work as should the terrain looks too smooth but the river should be in middle between peaks does not looks like it ...  If I remember correctly I got similar problems due to a bug in the downhill neighbors testing will take a look at my code if I spot what I did to prevent it.

Comment: You may be right. 
I will go through my river code again.

Can you share your river gen code? In your link there is code for the island shape/biome only. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @RishavSharan I found it. Assuming you got the same issue: If you hit local minimum (you are already on the smallest elevation) then you need to create lake by pushing position out of the main hill. I assume you are just incrementing in the first free direction instead which makes the ugly turning shape and then straight lines. You can also use sliding average of river direction for this instead (if you do not know where the hill is)

Answer (score 1):

Your river delta looks much like a tree. Here is some Python code using turtle for Graphics to draw a tree.

# You can edit this code and run it right here in the browser!
    # Try changing colors or adding your own shapes.

```
import turtle
from random import randint

def tree(length,n, ps):
    """ paints a branch of a tree with 2 smaller branches, like an Y"""
    if length < (length/n):
           return       # escape the function
    turtle.pensize(max(ps,1))     
    turtle.forward(length)        # paint the thik branch of the tree
    lb = 45+randint(-20,20)
    turtle.left(lb)          # rotate left for smaller "fork" branch
    tree(length * 0.5*(1+randint(-20,20)/100),length/n,ps-1) # create a smaller branch with 1/2 the lenght of the parent branch
    rb = 45+randint(-20,20)
    turtle.right(lb+rb)         # rotoate right for smaller "fork" branch
    tree(length * 0.6,length/n,ps-1)      # create second smaller branch
    turtle.left(rb)          # rotate back to original heading
    rt = randint(-20,20)
    turtle.right(rt)
    tree(length * 0.45,length/n,ps-1)
    turtle.left(rt)
    turtle.backward(length)       # move back to original position
    return              # leave the function, continue with calling program
turtle.left(90)
turtle.penup()
turtle.backward(250)
turtle.pendown()
tree(150,5,5)
```

Comment: Thanks Mats. I forgot to mention 1 thing. I am not looking to create a static shape but a procedurally generated one, which uses some seed value.

Comment: You can seed the tree by seeding randint() using seed().