# Generating & Growing regions on a 2D Grid Map

Tags: algorithm, game-development, godot, terrain, procedural-generation

I'm creating a 2D top-down game where terrain is procedurally generated.

The map is simply a 2D grid of tiles and the tiles are placed by sampling simplex noise. This gives fairly good results (especially when I add some warping (fbm? not sure) to the noise).

Question is, how can I generate biomes/regions on the map?

I was thinking of an algortihm where I place a few points denoting a region/biome on the map and then make them grow until they collide with another region (or reach an edge of the map)?

Something like this:
[image]

I tried writing some code but I thought I'd ask here instead - I'm sure someone has seen/done soemthing similar before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see [my Diamond&Square based terrain generator with biomes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36647622/2521214) for some alternative inspirations ...

Comment: See [Polygonal Map Generation for Games](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/).